# Pegar dados campos array() jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho os seguintes campos em array():

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="enviar" method="post">
    <table class="table" style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF !important;">
        <tr>
            <td>L</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td>Inicio</td>
            <td>Fim</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            for($i=1; $i<=$_GET['lotes']; $i++){ 

                if($i==$_GET['lotes']){
                    $dados['monta_lote'] = $dados['monta_lote'] + $dados['calcula_sobra'];
                }
        ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><span class="widget-thumb-body-stat label label-danger btn-circle" data-counter="counterup" data-value="1"><?php echo $i; ?></span></td>
            <td><span class="widget-thumb-body-stat label label-danger btn-circle" data-counter="counterup" data-value="<?php echo $dados['monta_lote']; ?>"><?php echo $dados['monta_lote']; ?></span></td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" value="<?php echo $_GET['mensagem']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="lote[]" name="lote[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="quantidade[]" name="quantidade[]" value="<?php echo $dados['monta_lote']; ?>">
                <input style="width:145px;" type="date" id="data_inicio[]" name="data_inicio[]" required>
                <input style="width:60px;" type="time" id="hora_inicio[]" name="hora_inicio[]" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:145px;" type="date" id="data_fim[]" name="data_fim[]" required>
                <input style="width:60px;" type="time" id="hora_fim[]" name="hora_fim[]" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            } 
        ?>
    </table>

    <div class="">
        <center>
            <button type="button" id="agendar" name="agendar" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar Lotes</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preciso que, ao clicar em Enviar, eu busque estes dados que estão nestes forms (que podem ser varios usando um foreach()), e envie via POST por ajax, tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#agendar').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "php/salvarLote.php",
          data: null,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
          },
          error: function(request, status, error) {
            // Aqui você trata um erro que possa vir a ocorrer
            // Exemplo:
            alert("Erro: " + request.responseText);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP salvarLote.php:

```
<?php 
  print_r($_POST); // return array()
?>
```

Mas ao enviar, não consigo repassar o conteúdo destes campos. O que está errado?

Comment: Postei o form completo, pra melhor analise, e ele é em array() porque pode ser vários campos destes, dependendo da quantidade que o cliente selecionou. Ex, selecionou 4, ele vai vir 4x este form ai. Como está no php.

Comment: Já sim, não chegou os dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar os dados do seu form usando o `.serializeArray` do jquery:

```
var data = $('#enviar').serializeArray();
```

e passar no seu ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/salvarLote.php",
      data: data,
      ...
```

Porém a estrutura que ele vai separar pode não ser ideal pra você, então eu recomendo essa biblioteca: https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject

Usando ela, você pode fazer assim:

```
var data = $('#enviar').serializeObject();
```

E ele vai conseguir montar a estrutura de acordo com a hierarquia que você especificou no HTML.